# jQuery v1.6.1 is not working with JSON parse

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I was using jQuery v1.3.2 for application development. I had to change it to jQuery 1.6.1 as part of a requirement. But Now the page itself is loading. Getting syntax error in JSON.parse line of code. It was working properly with jQuery v1.3.2. Is v1.6.1 is not backward compatible? I am using jquery.json-2.2.js. Please help in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using jquery.json-2.3.js, may be it solves your problem?

Comment: With this version it is giving me object expected error instead of syntax error

Comment: can you try with different JSON parsing library? http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has had [built-in string-to-JSON parsing](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) since version 1.4.1.

Comment: I have used the built in JSON parsing also. that is also not working.

Comment: I HAVE USED 'code' dataType:'text' 'code' on service call.. it solved the problem. thanks everyone.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used  `dataType:'text'` on service call.. it solved the problem.